# CKEditor - disable image drag and drop

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Problem:
When drag and drop images in Firefox into the CKEditor Window, the image are automaticly encoded in base64.

Now i want to disable this. I tried it with:

```
config.removePlugins = 'dragdrop';
```

but it's not working at all. Also tried it with a old Plugin (imagepaste), but not working either...

Is there a known solution out there? Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I tried to disable Base64 with `config.removePlugins = 'dragdrop,basket';`, but it didn't work at all.

Then I found [this link,](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Drag-and-drop-event-ckeditor) which helped me to solve this problem and [wrote a plugin](https://github.com/RogerRussel/ckeditor-dropoff) to do the job. Here it is with instructions:

To use it you have to create a folder inside of `./plugins` named `dropoff`.
Then create a file named `plugin.js` with this content:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('dropoff', {
     init: function (editor) {

          function rejectDrop(event) {
              event.data.preventDefault(true);
          };

          editor.on('contentDom', function() {
            editor.document.on('drop',rejectDrop);
          });

      }
});
```

After that, you have to register it on CKEditor's `config.js`.

```
config.extraPlugins = 'dropoff';
```

If you already using an extra plugin just put a `,` between them like this:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'mypreviousplugin,dropoff';
```

And be Happy! \o/

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm studying to improve my English, but it's still far from good.

Answer (score 2):

Here i found the solution to disable the drag and drop in ckeditor

```
ed.on('instanceReady', (ev) =>{
      CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.preventDefaultDropOnElement(ev.editor.document);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using a ckeditor5 custom build which includes the Base64UploadAdapter plugin. So, to disable this plugin for some particular views, I just added the "removePlugins" instruction to the editor configuration. Then, dragging and dropping images gets disabled.

```
  configEditor = {
    removePlugins: [ 'Base64UploadAdapter' ],
    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList'],
  };
```