# In CKEditor inline instances, how does one disable drag and dropping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

In CKEditor, how does one disable drag and dropping?

I do not want people to accidentally drag and drop other elements of the page into their respective editors.

I assume this requires intercepting browser specific events and blocking them but I am unsure how to do this in CKEditor.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

TAKEN FROM [THIS STACKOVERFLOW ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023407/ckeditor-disable-image-drag-and-drop)

At first I try disable with config.removePlugins = 'dragdrop,basket'; but it doesn't work at all.

Then I found this link, which help me to solved this problem and write a plugin to do the job.

Anyway I wrote here how to do the trick too.

With a Litle modification I wrote this plugin:

To use it you have to create a folder inside of ./plugins named "dropoff". Then create a file named plugin.js and put this content:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('dropoff', {
     init: function (editor) {

          function regectDrop(event) {
              event.data.preventDefault(true);
          };

          editor.on('contentDom', function() {
            editor.document.on('drop',regectDrop);
          });

      }
});
```

After it, you have to registrate it on ckeditor config.js.

config.extraPlugins = 'dropoff';

If you already using an extra pluging just put a "," before like this:

config.extraPlugins = 'mypreviousplugin,dropoff';

And be Happy! \o/

Comment: Already tried that. That does not work in Firefox 44, I can still accidentally drag elements into the inline ckeditor instances.

Comment: @cantchoos tryed that?

Comment: Still doesn't work, sorry :( I cannot accidentally drag non contenteditable fields however so that is at least fixed. I do not want other fields to be able to be dragged in other fields (images from my logo down to the body for instance) if that makes sense. Sorry for the long delay I haven't came back to this issue until now :)