# Disable drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

Does anyone know how to disable the CKEditor Drag and Drop?  I realize some code must be added to the config.js file and have tried the suggested methods found on the internet but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023407/ckeditor-disable-image-drag-and-drop?

Comment: So, what was the suggested method you found on the internet and it didn't work?

Comment: I tried everything on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023407/ckeditor-disable-image-drag-and-drop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CKEditor - disable image drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023407/ckeditor-disable-image-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 1):

Please try putting below code into HTML page directly (where CKEditor is used) and then try to drag&drop something inside the editor. The code will work in IE9+ and modern browsers.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
 // editor configuration can be put here...
});
editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function( evt ) {
    editor.on( 'contentDom', function( e ) {
        e.editor.editable().attachListener( editor.document, 'drop', function( event ) {
            event.data.preventDefault();
        } );
    } );
});
```